# Python: Kivy: Divide two number from a single TextInput

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Simple question, how can i divide two numbers from a single InputBox? I have no idea, example, i have only one inputbox and i write two numbers "40 10" how can i divide automatically this? Here the code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.listview import ListView

class Widget(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Widget, self) .__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2

        self.add_widget(Label(text="RPM"))
        self.rpm = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.rpm)

        btn1 = Button(text="Division:")
        btn1.bind(on_press=self.buttonClicked)
        self.add_widget(btn1)
```

Example of what i need:

```
    def buttonClicked(self, btn):
        self.rpm.text(first input / second input)
        x = self.rpm.text
        popup = Popup(title='Result', content=x, size_hint=(None, 
        None), size=(500, 90))
        popup.open()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure is the next:

- Get the text from `TextInput`
- Separate it by the space
- Verify that only 2 terms exist
- Convert it to float, so an error may appear, exceptions must be used.
- And for the last one we establish the popup with a Label that contains the text.

---

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.0.6")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

class Widget(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Widget, self) .__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2

        self.add_widget(Label(text="RPM"))
        self.rpm = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.rpm)

        btn1 = Button(text="Division:")
        btn1.bind(on_press=self.buttonClicked)
        self.add_widget(btn1)

    def buttonClicked(self, btn):
        texts = self.rpm.text.split()
        if len(texts) == 2:
            try:
                x, y = map(float, texts)
                res = x/y
                popup = Popup(title='Result', content=Label(text=str(res)), size_hint=(None, None), size=(500, 90))
                popup.open()
            except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError):
                print("error")

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Widget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

This type of interfaces are few useful since the user could place anything, the appropriate thing is to validate the text while it is being written as for example to accept a certain set of characters.

Another improvement is that it is separated into 2 `TextInput`s.

Comment: Thanks. I try to insert another TextInput, but in the GridLayout i dont know how to change the position of the TextInput for place it near to the first

Comment: @Abunis Check the documentation, there is everything.